# How can parallelism affect number of results?

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, parallel-processing

I have a fairly complex query that looks something like this:

```
create table Items(SomeOtherTableID int,SomeField int)
create table SomeOtherTable(Id int,GroupID int)
with cte1 as
(
    select 
        SomeOtherTableID,COUNT(*) SubItemCount 
    from 
        Items t 
    where 
        t.SomeField is not null 
    group by 
        SomeOtherTableID

),cte2 as
(
    select
        tc.SomeOtherTableID,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by a.GroupID order by tc.SubItemCount desc) SubItemRank
    from 
        Items t
        inner join SomeOtherTable a on a.Id=t.SomeOtherTableID 
        inner join cte1 tc on tc.SomeOtherTableID=t.SomeOtherTableID
    where 
        t.SomeField is not null 

),cte3 as
(
    select 
        SomeOtherTableID 
    from 
        cte2 
    where 
        SubItemRank=1
)
select 
    * 
from 
    cte3 t1 
    inner join cte3 t2 on t1.SomeOtherTableID<t2.SomeOtherTableID 
option (maxdop 1)
```

The query is such that **cte3** is filled with **6222** *distinct* results. In the final **select**, I am performing a cross join on **cte3** with itself, (so that I can compare every value in the table with every other value in the table at a later point). Notice the final line :

```
option (maxdop 1)
```

Apparently, this switches off parallelism.

So, with **6222** results rows in **cte3**, I would expect (6222*6221)/2, or **19353531** results in the subsequent cross joining select, and with the final **maxdop** line in place, that is indeed the case.

However, when I remove the **maxdop** line, the number of results jumps to **19380454**. I have 4 cores on my dev box.

WTF? Can anyone explain why this is? Do I need to reconsider previous queries that cross join in this way?

Comment: Have you looked at the set difference to see what rows are in set 2 that are not in set 1?

Comment: set 1, set 2? Do you mean cte1 and cte2? If so, the final join is only on cte3, which has a single field of distinct results (I have checked), so what goes on in cte1 and cte2 shouldn't matter right?

Comment: No, sorry, what I mean is result set.  You get two different results, I'm wondering what extra rows are in the result when you turn maxdop off.  It might give you a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: Kind of tricky with 19 million results in memory because I don't have enough memory for both result sets. Of course, inserting cte3 into a declared table and using that 2nd table works as expected.

Comment: Is it consistently reproducable with and without MAXDOP every single time? What about MAXDOP 2?

Comment: its consistently reproducable

Comment: MAXDOP 1 gives correct number of results, MAXDOP 2 gives 19365141 results, no MAXDOP setting (implicitly 4?) gives 19380454 results. Consistently.

Comment: I realize this is a very old question, but by chance, do you recall the SQL Server version running at the time this behavior was seen? I'm currently seeing almost exactly the same thing, on `10.50.1600.1` (I'm aware this is unsupported!). If someone can point to a specific bug report related to this, that would also be very helpful.

Comment: @Dan See my comment below to Mitch Wheat about what I believe to be the true nature of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from a bug, parallelism should not affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a similar parallism bug with [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=328811) too

Or are you using [snaphot isolation](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=384262), another bug too? There are also some blogs that demonstrate snapshot isolation being turned off temporarily under certain conditions.

Edit:

Going back to Snapshot isolation, number 3 here: [Six reasons you should be nervous about parallelism](https://sqlblog.org/2009/03/21/six-reasons-you-should-be-nervous-about-parallelism)